# Convert MYSQL date to CCYYMMDD

Tags: mysql

As it mentioned in title, how can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? What MySQL date? What is `C` in your view? This is not rentacoder.com

Comment: If you demonstrate your efforts - ie some code - you would get a better response ... this kind of thing is simple to do if you read the help sections of either PHP or MySQL - so we need an example of your problem

Comment: By default [MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) so what is the question?

Comment: @Gorden: he asks for a date formatted without the dashes. That's a different format than what he asks.

Comment: Why should MySQL care about Date format?  That's a rendering issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Date_format`, i.e.

```
select date_format(fieldname,'%Y%m%d') from ...;
```

You can find more information in the manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Simple way to check from the command line:

```
select date_format(now(),'%Y%m%d');
```

This just formats today as CCYYMMDD.

Comment: The default format is CCYY-MM-DD, he wants CCYYMMDD. So without the dashes.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options ...

Use MySQL on select -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

example :

`select date_format(<yourDateField>,'%Y%m%d') from ...;`

Use PHP on the result -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

example :

```
$date = new DateTime($yourDateField);
echo $date->format('Ymd');
```